# What happens when a Native American is party to a crime on a different tribe's reservation?

Tags: united-states, tribal

Some interactions involving native Americans on tribal land are subject to tribal law instead of state and federal law.

Is a N.A. from a different tribe subject to the host tribe's jurisdiction like a native or is he considered like a regular American?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Duro v. Reina*, [495 U.S. 676](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep495/usrep495676/usrep495676.pdf) (1990), the Supreme Court held that Indian tribes do not have criminal jurisdiciton over nonmember Indians. The rationale was that there had been a "divestiture of sovereignty" over "relations between an Indian tribe and nonmembers of the tribe" ([p. 686](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep495/usrep495676/usrep495676.pdf#page=11)). As a result, prosecution of "outsiders" "could only have come to the Tribe by delegation from Congress" (*ibid*.).

Congress subsequently passed [Public Law 101-511](https://www.congress.gov/101/statute/STATUTE-104/STATUTE-104-Pg1856.pdf) (5 November 1990), which at section [8077(b)](https://www.congress.gov/101/statute/STATUTE-104/STATUTE-104-Pg1856.pdf#page=37), amended [25 USC § 1301](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=(title:25%20section:1301%20edition:prelim)%20OR%20(granuleid:USC-prelim-title25-section1301)&f=treesort&edition=prelim&num=0&jumpTo=true) to recognize that the "powers of self-government" of an Indian tribe include the power to "exercise criminal jurisdiction over *all Indians*." As initially passed, this change was subject to a [sunset provision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunset_provision) on September 30, 1991. But the change was made permanent by [Public Law 102-137](https://www.congress.gov/102/statute/STATUTE-105/STATUTE-105-Pg646.pdf), which removed the sunset provision.

Now, for crimes that are not within exclusive federal jurisdiction by other statutes (e.g. [18 U.S.C. § 1153](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=(title:18%20section:1153%20edition:prelim)%20OR%20(granuleid:USC-prelim-title18-section1153)&f=treesort&edition=prelim&num=0&jumpTo=true)), an Indian tribe has jurisdiction over offences committed within their borders, even over nonmember Indians. These are generally limited to non-major (misdemeanor) offences.